# counter doesnt increment in update with unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, int, counter, increment

I have a simple code that makes my character jump,

My character can jump as long as he's current jump is lower than the maxNumber of jumps.

and every time he jumps i add 1 to his current jump.

my problem is the jump counter doesnt always add one? even when the character jumps, he jumps with no problems but the counter doesnt always respond.

he is allowed to jump twice, but from time to time the player does hes first jump without anything being added to his current jump.

```
 // Jumping
public int maxNoJumps = 2;
public int currentJumpNo = 0;
public bool canPlayerJump = false;
public float JumpVelocity = 25;

 void Update () 
 {

grounded = Physics2D.Linecast (transform.position, groundCheck.position, 1 << LayerMask.NameToLayer ("Ground"));

  if (grounded)
  {
   currentJumpNo = 0;
  }

 // SETTING IF PLAYER IS ABLE TO JUMP
 if (currentJumpNo < maxNoJumps) 
 {
     canPlayerJump = true;
 } else 
 {
     canPlayerJump = false;
 }


 // IF PLAYER PRESSES SPACE AND IS ABLE TO JUMP
 if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && canPlayerJump) 
 {
     currentJumpNo+=1;
     rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (rb2d.velocity.x, JumpVelocity);

 }
}
```

like i said the player jumps even when the counter doesnt go up allowing him sometimes to jump 3 times.

also i have tried it in fixed update and it's still the same and incrementing in different ways.

thank in advance for helping

Comment: do you want to make something like double jump, while player is in the air he can jumps again ?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest keeping your jumps seperate and using booleans instead.

For instance instead of

```
if (currentJumpNo < maxNoJumps) 
 {
     canPlayerJump = true;
 } else 
{
    canPlayerJump = false;
}
```

use:

```
if (grounded) 
 {
     canPlayerJump = true;
     doubleJump = true;
 } else if(doubleJump)
{
    canPlayerJump = true;
}
else
{
canPlayerJump = false;
}
```

and then in your jump section

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.Space) && canPlayerJump) 
  {
     doubleJump = (grounded)? true:false;
     rb2d.velocity = new Vector2 (rb2d.velocity.x, JumpVelocity);

 }
```

this basically says if they are grounded before they jump they still have double jump. If they are not grounded they lose the double jump.

I hope very much that this will help you in your project. If the problem persists, just reply and I will see if I can create an alternate jump function that should work as well.

Comment: Thank you for replying, and sorry its taken me too long to reply. been caught up with work so Unity has fallen behind, anyways... i did have my jump controlled by booleans first but i wanted to allow the player to jump even when he has just stepped off the edge of a platform as well as being on the platform. and i couldnt find a way of doing this hence why i switched to the charatcer always having 2 jumps. ideally i would have it so that after a time (like one second after stepping off the edge) he can no longer jump, and continues to fall downwards. if you get what i mean

Comment: I also found out what i was doing wrong with my first problem, the reason the counter wasnt incrementing was because my groundcheck wasnt completly clearing the ground straight away (i had it set too low) meaning that the counter was going up to 1 but was being reset to 0 again because when ground he's current jump number is set to 0.... btw im kind writing this a lil stoned just as a heads up so if people are reading this and it isnt making that much sense then this is why.

Comment: I would suggest a coroutine running alongside then, So when he is no longer grounded and the character has both his jumps, then do: yield return new waitforseconds and then deactivate the ability to jump.I hope this makes sense